# How to resolve Load Balancer redirecting to only master or slave in Apache2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, jmeter, apache2, load-balancing

I have 1 load balancer and a master and a slave. The load balancer is supposed to redirect to either Master or Slave, however, I have encountered a problem when testing my website through JMeter, the load balancer either sends all the requests to the master or the slave. This is fixed when I restart the apache2 load balancer but after rerunning the JMeter test multiple times, it goes back to sending all the requests to either the master or the slave. How can this be fixed?

I tried restating apache2 load balancer, toggle with settings in the JMeter.

Comment: The way you describe the situation sounds like the lb does _exactly_ what it's supposed to do. However, it also sounds like server administration (see [help/on-topic]), and does not have any information about your current setup, so we have no clue what's going on, and consequently how to fix (see [ask]). All in all: Sounds off-topic here, suggesting to find a stackexchange site where it's on topic, but please provide them with a [mcve]. (Or edit to make it about programming)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your load balancer configuration you can:

1. Add [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) and use a custom DNS resolver so each thread (virtual user) will get the underlying IP address on its own and not relying on Java DNS Caching
2. [Disable DSN Caching](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420655--Disable-DNS-caching) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0
   ```
3. If your load balancer decides where to send the request basing on source IP address you can go for [IP Spoofing](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-send-jmeter-requests-from-different-ips-sumit-kumar/)